# How to translate string in CMS repeater in Kentico?

Tags: c#, asp.net, kentico

I try to do multilingual version of my website in Kentico CMS. In one webpart I have CMSRepeater:

```
<cms:CMSRepeater ID="rptProducts" runat="server"
                     Path="/Products/%" 
                     ClassNames="MyWeb.ProductRestaurant" 
                     TransformationName="MyWeb.ProductRestaurant.ProductsList"
                     SelectOnlyPublished="false" 
                     StopProcessing="true"
                     ZeroRowsText="There are no products to show" />
```

How to make string in "ZeroRowsText" changeable? I tried to put label there and then set the value of this string in code behind using CMShelper to translate resources:

> myLiteral.Text =
>   CMS.GlobalHelper.ResHelper.GetString("RestaurantOffer.ThereAreNoProductstoShow");

but unfortunately it doesn't work. Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In code behind you should be able to set the property on the CMSRepeater object:

rptProducts.ZeroRowsText = "Your text"